# open and Play a transport stream on Android (mpeg2-ts)

Tags: android, networking, stream, multimedia, mpeg

It's me again.

I am trying to play a TS file I am getting via http (mpeg2-ts) on android. I already tried VideoView as follows:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://192.168.0.27:7522/upnp/channelstream/9.ts"));
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

but it just says it cant open the video (I also used the internet permission). After some research, I found out that android 4 brings in OpenMAX, with which you can open .ts files. It seems that you need the NDK for that, but I don't know how to use it. Are there any example codes for OpenMAX or are there any other (better) methods to play the .ts file?

I also tried out the Android version of VLC, and it was able to play the .ts file. I just need to know how VLC did it.

Greets

Comment: Hi C0dR :) I am facing the same issue.If you have found any solution, or you have any suggestion. Please please tell me. :(